# A faster way to replace multiple string value in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace multiple string values in a column and I understand that I can use the `replace()` to do it one by one. Given I need to replace more than 10 string values, I am just wondering if there's a faster way to replace a number of string values to the same value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["US", "Japan", "UK", "China", "Peru", "Germany"]})
df.replace({'a' : { 'Japan' : 'Germany', 'UK' : 'Germany', 'China' : 'Germany' }})
```

Expected output:

```
         a
0       US
1  Germany
2  Germany
3  Germany
4     Peru
5  Germany
```

Comment: Try `df.replace('Japan|UK|China', 'Germany', regex=True)`. The `df.replace()` can handel regualr expressions, there you can combine multiple strings/groups.

Comment: How many different string values do you have in your column?

Comment: 15.  @DaniMesejo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
#60k rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["US", "Japan", "UK", "China", "Peru", "Germany"] * 10000})

In [161]: %timeit df['a'] = df.a.map({ 'Japan' : 'Germany', 'UK' : 'Germany', 'China' : 'Germany' }).fillna(df.a)
12.4 ms ± 501 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [162]: %timeit df['a'] = np.where(df.a.isin(['Japan','UK','China']), 'Germany', df.a)
4.27 ms ± 379 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)   

#assignment raise error in test
In [1632]: %timeit df.replace({'a' : { 'Japan' : 'Germany', 'UK' : 'Germany', 'China' : 'Germany' }})
7.85 ms ± 462 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Slowier solution:

```
In [157]: %timeit df.replace('Japan|UK|China', 'Germany', regex=True)
218 ms ± 842 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I think a more thorough test should include the reassignment, which should be as a Series, either as a direct assignment or with assign method.

Comment: @sammywemmy - good idea.

Comment: You always have some nice solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = df.replace('Japan|UK|China', 'Germany', regex=True)
```

Comment: added to my answer.

Comment: I see your point. It is a slow way to do it. Thank you.